# How to retrurn custom Error response in WebApi

Tags: c#, api

I have a model below

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return error response like below if any field is empty

```
{
"status": 400,
"errors": {
    "UserId": [
        {
            "code":"Required",
            "message": "Missing data for requiredfield"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

how do I return this custom message with each field's name?

Comment: In .net Core I would do a return this.BadRequest(errorMsg) in my controller method after checking controller method arguments.

Comment: return StatusCode(400, "Your custom message or json");?

Comment: Have a look at [Handle validations, exceptions and return consistent response](http://vmsdurano.com/asp-net-core-and-web-api-a-custom-wrapper-for-managing-exceptions-and-consistent-responses/) or [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/learn-about-web-api-validation/).

Comment: @user743414 I use web api, not core.